# I have a time and a time zone - no date. How do I convert that time to another time zone?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

From the database I get a time as a string: `13:20:00`, I get a time zone: `America/New_York` and a date as a string `2023-01-2` from a linked table

How do convert that time to America/Los_Angeles (would return `10:20:00`) or any other time zone?

I am using the moment.js library.

I tried:

```js
const t     = "2023-01-24 13:20:00"
const tzOut = 'America/New_York'
const tzIn  = "America/Los_Angeles"
const m     = moment(t, "YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS").tz(tzIn)
return m.tz(tzOut).format("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS"); 
// Returns "2023-01-24 16:20:00"
```

And this works, but if I change the time zones around:

```
const t     = "2023-01-24 13:20:00"
const tzIn  = 'America/New_York'
const tzOut = "America/Los_Angeles"
const m     = moment(t, "YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS").tz(tzIn)
return m.tz(tzOut).format("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS"); 
// Returns "2023-01-24 13:20:00", should be "2023-01-24 10:20:00"
```

I believe this is because I am in the America/Los_Angeles time zone, moment.js is factoring this in and `moment(t,"YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS").tz(tzIn)` is becoming 16:20:00. I want it to become 13:20:00 but in America/New_York time zone.

So it seems I am on the wrong track - how should I be doing this?

Edited to add dates.

Comment: Side note: obviously you understand that there is no general way to achieve correct results with just time, don't you?

Comment: You realize that timezone changes based on time of year?

Comment: Yes, you are both correct! I fixed my code to add a date and it still does the same thing. Giver me a few minutes to edit my question to account for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're confusing `moment.tz()` and the `.tz()` method on a moment object. If you need to parse a date in a specific timezone, use [`moment.tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) to construct a new moment object like usual, but with an extra parameter that is the timezone. If you need to convert to a different timezone, then use the [`.tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) method.

In your code, the first time you need use `moment.tz()`, while the second time you need to use the `.tz()` method. Change your code to this:

```
const t     = "2023-01-24 13:20:00"
const tzIn  = 'America/New_York'
const tzOut = "America/Los_Angeles"
const m     = moment.tz(t, "YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS", tzIn)
return m.tz(tzOut).format("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS")
```